# Stream N1QL query results in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++, couchbase-java-api, couchbase-java-client

My N1QL query returns around 3.5 million documents. Is there a way in which I can stream those documents to the client?
I see there is a kafka connector available in couchbase but seems like it works on DCP wherein all the mutations to the documents are send to kafka.
I have a fixed N1QL query and want the query results to be streamed.

Comment: Have you looked into using Reactive/Async - https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html#reactive-and-async-apis

Comment: N1QL streams the results when it ready.  https://couchbase.live/examples/basic-java-query-named-param checkout. Also n1ql can project document key, stream and use SDK to Fetch document from kv parallel  Reactive/Async

Comment: We used eventing with cURL posts to stream couchbase document mutations to our services. It works pretty well. Maybe that is an alternative for you approach, instead of quering 3.5 million documents at once, why now stream each document mutation with eventing